# How to Handle Radio Button List Option change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I hava a RadioButtonList control on my page that has multiple option.I want to handle change of its options and, according to value of selected option, do work.

This does not work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#RadioButtonList1').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("yes");
            }
        });
    });
```

How I can Handle that?

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to bind the inputs themselves, not their group:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RadioButtonList1 input').change(function () {
        // The one that fires the event is always the
        // checked one; you don't need to test for this
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: He said,that he has a multiple checkboxes.Using 'id' is not good for this solution.

Comment: I believe his ID is generated by ASP as a div around a group of <input type="radio" /> elements.

Answer (score 1):

May be this one help you:)

```
$('form#package_information_id').on('change','.shipment_type_radio_class',function(){

             var currentselval = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked');
             //console.log(currentselval);
             if(currentselval.val()=='dropoff') 
             {
                $('.pickup_detail_class').hide();
             }else
             {
                $('.pickup_detail_class').show();
             }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>``
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

            var val = "";
            val = $('[id*=rblTest]').find('input:checked').val();
            if (val != "" && val != undefined) {
                alert("Selected item value is : " + val)
            }

        });


</script>
```

Comment: It is already answered. Though it is useful, this seems to be rephrasing both the question and answer.